# Delete Selected Items From Google Merchant XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

i want to remove **g:price=0** OR **out of stock** OR **no image** ITEMS from my Google Merchant xml feed by PHP.
i'm trying for hours and hours; but could not find a solution yet..

example: (if i have xml like this; the new xml must list only the second item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
 <channel>
  <title><![CDATA[example title]]></title>
  <link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></link>
  <description><![CDATA[example description]]></description>

<item>
<g:additional_image_link><![CDATA[]]></g:additional_image_link>  
<g:image><![CDATA[]]></g:image>
<g:availability><![CDATA[out of stock]]></g:availability>
<g:price>0.00 TRY</g:price>
</item>
<item> 
<g:image><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/image.jpg]]></g:image>
<g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
<g:price>100.00 TRY</g:price>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Could someone help me? Expected output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
 <channel>
  <title><![CDATA[example title]]></title>
  <link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></link>
  <description><![CDATA[example description]]></description>

<item> 
<g:image><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/image.jpg]]></g:image>
<g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
<g:price>100.00 TRY</g:price>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: thank you Sahil.. i added to my question.

Comment: Can you share complete XML response?

Comment: updated my question again :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` for extracting nodes and removing un-required nodes.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793233)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
     <channel>
      <title><![CDATA[example title]]></title>
      <link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></link>
      <description><![CDATA[example description]]></description>
    <item>
        <g:additional_image_link><![CDATA[]]></g:additional_image_link>  
        <g:image><![CDATA[]]></g:image>
        <g:availability><![CDATA[out of stock]]></g:availability>
        <g:price>0.00 TRY</g:price>

    </item>
    <item> 
        <g:image><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/image.jpg]]></g:image>
        <g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
        <g:price>100.00 TRY</g:price>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
XML;

$array = array("g:image", "g:price", "g:availability");
$domObject = new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadXML($string);
$results = $domObject->getElementsByTagName("item");
$nodesToRemove = array();
foreach ($results as $node)
{
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $innerNode)
    {
        if ($innerNode instanceof DOMElement && in_array($innerNode->tagName, $array))
        {
            if ($innerNode->tagName == "g:image" && empty($innerNode->textContent))
            {
                $nodesToRemove[] = $innerNode->parentNode;
                break;
            } elseif ($innerNode->tagName == "g:price" && preg_match("/\b0+(\.[0]+)\b/", $innerNode->textContent))
            {
                $nodesToRemove[] = $innerNode->parentNode;
                break;
            } elseif ($innerNode->tagName == "g:availability" && $innerNode->textContent == "out of stock")
            {
                $nodesToRemove[] = $innerNode->parentNode;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($nodesToRemove as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $domObject->saveXML();
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
     <channel>
      <title><![CDATA[example title]]></title>
      <link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></link>
      <description><![CDATA[example description]]></description>

    <item> 
        <g:image><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/image.jpg]]></g:image>
        <g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
        <g:price>100.00 TRY</g:price>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```